# Trait bound's problem while processing Result<Vec<u8>, Box<dyn Error>>

Tags: rust, future

I'm trying to build a matrix bot using [matrix-rust-sdk](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-rust-sdk/) based on the following [example](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-rust-sdk/blob/main/examples/image_bot/src/main.rs).

```rust
use std::error::Error;

use matrix_sdk::{
    self,
    attachment::AttachmentConfig,
    config::SyncSettings,
    ruma::events::room::message::{
        MessageType, OriginalSyncRoomMessageEvent, RoomMessageEventContent,
    },
    Client, Room, RoomState,
};
use url::Url;

async fn process_request(request: String) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    Ok(vec![1, 2, 3])
}

async fn on_room_message(event: OriginalSyncRoomMessageEvent, room: Room) {
    if room.state() != RoomState::Joined {
        return;
    }
    let MessageType::Text(text_content) = event.content.msgtype else { return };

    if text_content.body.contains("!image") {
        let image_response = process_request(text_content.body).await;
        match image_response {
            Ok(img_data) => room
                .send_attachment(
                    "image",
                    &mime::IMAGE_JPEG,
                    img_data,
                    AttachmentConfig::new(),
                )
                .await
                .unwrap(),
            Err(e) => room
                .send(RoomMessageEventContent::text_plain(format!("{e}")), None)
                .await
                .unwrap(),
        };
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let homeserver_url =
        Url::parse(&"http://matrix.com").expect("Couldn't parse the homeserver URL");
    let client = Client::new(homeserver_url).await.unwrap();

    client
        .matrix_auth()
        .login_username("username", "password")
        .initial_device_display_name("command bot")
        .await?;

    client.add_event_handler(move |ev, room| on_room_message(ev, room));

    Ok(())
}
```

This sample cause the following error during build

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[closure@src/main.rs:56:30: 56:45]: EventHandler<_, _>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:56:30
    |
56  |     client.add_event_handler(move |ev, room| on_room_message(ev, room));
    |            ----------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `EventHandler<_, _>` is not implemented for closure `[closure@src/main.rs:56:30: 56:45]`
    |            |
    |            required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
note: required by a bound in `matrix_sdk::Client::add_event_handler`
   --> /home/user/.cargo/git/checkouts/matrix-rust-sdk-1f4927f82a3d27bb/e862470/crates/matrix-sdk/src/client/mod.rs:602:12
    |
602 |         H: EventHandler<Ev, Ctx>,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Client::add_event_handler`
```

I'm struggling to understand the reason of this error because if I don't process the Error in the match case everything is fine. For example like in this case everything is compiling correctly.

```rust
use std::error::Error;

use matrix_sdk::{
    self,
    attachment::AttachmentConfig,
    config::SyncSettings,
    ruma::events::room::message::{
        MessageType, OriginalSyncRoomMessageEvent, RoomMessageEventContent,
    },
    Client, Room, RoomState,
};
use url::Url;

async fn process_request(request: String) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    Ok(vec![1, 2, 3])
}

// async fn on_room_message(event: OriginalSyncRoomMessageEvent, room: Room) {
//     if room.state() != RoomState::Joined {
//         return;
//     }
//     let MessageType::Text(text_content) = event.content.msgtype else { return };

//     if text_content.body.contains("!image") {
//         let image_response = process_request(text_content.body).await;
//         match image_response {
//             Ok(img_data) => room
//                 .send_attachment(
//                     "image",
//                     &mime::IMAGE_JPEG,
//                     img_data,
//                     AttachmentConfig::new(),
//                 )
//                 .await
//                 .unwrap(),
//             Err(e) => room
//                 .send(RoomMessageEventContent::text_plain(format!("{e}")), None)
//                 .await
//                 .unwrap(),
//         };
//     }
// }
async fn on_room_message(event: OriginalSyncRoomMessageEvent, room: Room) {
    if room.state() != RoomState::Joined {
        return;
    }
    let MessageType::Text(text_content) = event.content.msgtype else { return };

    if text_content.body.contains("!image") {
        let image_response = process_request(text_content.body).await.unwrap();
        room.send_attachment(
            "image",
            &mime::IMAGE_JPEG,
            image_response,
            AttachmentConfig::new(),
        )
        .await
        .unwrap();
    }
}
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let homeserver_url =
        Url::parse(&"http://matrix.com").expect("Couldn't parse the homeserver URL");
    let client = Client::new(homeserver_url).await.unwrap();

    client
        .matrix_auth()
        .login_username("username", "password")
        .initial_device_display_name("command bot")
        .await?;

    client.add_event_handler(move |ev, room| on_room_message(ev, room));

    Ok(())
}
```

`unwrap()`, or `map_err(|err| format!("GPU node error: {err}"));` fix the issue, but I don't understand why

Comment: Please provide the missing `use` statements that make your code compilable. We can't help you without being able to reproduce your error.

Comment: Whole example is based on the example from matrix-rust-sdk, which is located [here](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-rust-sdk/blob/main/examples/image_bot/src/main.rs) with only difference of using additional `async fn process_request(request: String) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Box<dyn Error>>`

Comment: Please [do not (only) link to external code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code). An SO question should be fully self-contained.

Comment: @Finomnis thanks for pointing, do I need to add dependencies as well?

Comment: It's a plus because it makes reproducibility very easy, but it's very rare that people do it so I don't usually ask for it.